# Wordpress crashes after migration on another server

Tags: php, wordpress, migration

I migrated an existing website created in wordpress to another server. I succesfully imported the database from the old web, succesfully copied all the files to the new FTP and updated wp.config to new DB name, user and password. I even updated links in DB, so they do not point to the old URL.

However when I try to recover a password for the first time after migration, the password is sent to the e-mail, I even get to generate new password, but as soon as I click on the dashboard,the  whole wordpress crashes. Even the site is unaccessible, but FTP works.

Also it looks like it crashes only once after the migration. Once the server is restarted, it works just fine and recovers passwords well too.

Beforehand I enabled WP_DEBUG_LOG and it said this:

```
[20-Nov-2017 18:14:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(/var/www/hosting/HOSTING/sources/themes/name/inc/meta.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/hosting/HOSTING/sources/themes/name/single.php on line 12
[20-Nov-2017 18:14:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/hosting/HOSTING/sources/themes/name/inc/meta.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/hosting/HOSTING/sources/themes/name/single.php on line 12
```

I also enabled WP_DEBUG and it reports the same error plus one error more:

```
[19-Nov-2017 13:04:46 UTC] PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '/var/www/hosting/HOSTING/sources/themes/name/inc/nav.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/hosting/HOSTING/sources/themes/name/archive.php on line 24
```

Could these missing files be the source of this problem?

Comment: Does this file actually exist? `/var/www/hosting/HOSTING/sources/themes/name/inc/nav.php`? After moving all the files, have you fixed the filesystem permission so that the web server user has access to everything?

Comment: All the permanent links are turned off before migration and turned on after migration right ?

Comment: @MattClark That file does not exist, hence the error. But it did not exist even on the old server. I also did not change any permissions.

Comment: With WP debugging disabled, do you see any other errors in the webserver log?

Comment: @MattClark Not errors, just accessing information. But I found out, that when I reset the password, I can't access the site (it seems down), but other people can access it just fine.

Comment: Clear your cookies or try an incognito tab? Could be stale local cache?

Comment: @visrey I did not change anything with permalinks. None of the tutorials about migration I read even mentioned it.

Comment: you updated links but for sure you forget to update file paths, right ? some plugin store in the database paths of some file and after migration the path become unreachable. Check it

Answer (score 0):

Is that the local path on your current hosting server, or the path from the old server?

Can you still access the old/original site or has it been removed? If you still have access and your database is less than a 500MB, try the "WP All-in-One Migration" plugin. Otherwise, try transferring your files again. If possible, via the server's backend interface, i.e., File Manager in cPanel, or other.).

Comment: I can access the old site and I tried to transfer those files again, but it still crashed. I am afraid, that I will not be able to use that plugin, because the owner of the site does not want to install any additional plugins.